# Can I edit a global vector using multiple threads in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I currently have a code which works well, but I am learning C++, and hence would like to rid myself of any newbie mistakes. Basically the code is

```
vector<vector<float>> gAbs;

void functionThatAddsEntryTogAbs(){
    ...
    gAbs.pushback(value);
}

int main(){
    thread thread1 = thread(functionThatAddsEntryTogAbs,args);
    thread thread2 = thread(functionThatAddsEntryTogAbs,args);

    thread1.join(); thread2.join();

    std::sort(gAbs.begin(),gAbs.end());
    writeDataToFile(gAbs,"filename.dat");
}
```

For instance I remember learning that there are only a few instances where global variables are the right choice. My initial thought was just to have the threads write to the file, but then I cannot guarantee that the data is sorted (which I need), which is my I use `std::sort`. Are there any suggestions of how to improve this, and what are some alternatives that the more experiences programmers would use instead?

The code needs to be as fast as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general having two threads add entries to a global vector is not my idea of how to write fast code. In order to make access to the vector thread safe you will have to lock the vector which will slow things down a lot. Would it not be possible to have each thread write to it's own vector (global if necessary) and then combine the vectors at the end before sorting the combined vector.

Comment: It's pretty much always a bad idea to have concurrent writes in your code, and if I remember correctly, std::vector isn't thread-safe. If your function `functionThatAddsEntryTogAbs` does more than just adding an entry (computes something before), I would advise you to take a look at Mutexes. These are basically locks, and you could simply acquire it just before the insertion, and unlock it afterwards, to still allow the computation to be done in multiple threads

Comment: Thank you @john, that seems to be a solution that is less dirty – I assumed my solution would be faster because I avoid the extra step of joining all the vectors together, but I'll give this a try.

Comment: I'll have a look at Mutexes, thanks @Ladislus

Comment: Note that if your code dosen't do anything too computationally intensive, adding a mutex could be slower than a sequential program, as you would have the overhead of creating/launching the threads, that would have to wait for others to finish anyway. @john 's answers seems a lot better, doing it in a divide-to-conquer manner, and it would also remove the global variables, that are (almost) alway evil

Comment: @PeterDanielJohannsen Bottom line is that it depends on the details of exactly what you are doing. You should experiment and learn as you go.

Comment: @PeterDanielJohannsen And something that is true whether threaded or unthreaded is that pre-allocating your vectors to their known sizes will save a lot of time, especially if the vectors are large.

Comment: There's one more issue here that i don't see mentioned here: You sort the global vector before you know, if the modifications are done. You should join the threads before calling `sort`. This however would make it preferrable to the logic executed on one of the threads on the main thread after starting the other thread, since you'd otherwise just be waiting for another thread doing the work you could do on the main thread instead of waiting. If threads are worth it here at all very much depends on the runtime of the `...` part and whether it has to access `aAbs`.

Comment: Btw: Depending on the logic in `functionThatAddsEntryTogAbs` you could consider using `std::async` with a function returning `std::vector<float>` and use the futures returned in the main thread to fill `gAbs`.

Comment: By default `std::vector` is not thread safe. That does not stop use from using threads, but you must synchronize them. In this particular example there is no guarantee that both the calls to the `functionThatAddsEntryTogAbs` will be executed in the order you want, if at all. So this means if both threads the same time try to write to the vector one will be successful and the other not.                   tldr: If you really need something like this use synchronize techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and modify global resources, including containers from different threads, but you have to protect them from doing that at the same time. Some exceptions are: no modifications are possible, the container itself is not changed and the threads are working on separate entries.

In your code, entries are added to the container, so you need mutexes, but by doing that your parallel code probably doesn't gain you much in speed. A better way could be to know how many entries need to be added, add empty entries (just initialize) and then assign ranges to the threads, so they can fill in the entries.

Comment: Yeah I always know exactly how many points there are, so that would def work. Would you suggest using float[][] instead of vector<vector<>>? The data short be sorted automatically using your suggestion, in which case there's no benefit of using vector, right?

Comment: @PeterDanielJohannsen irregardless of storage used, unless operations are atomic or were fenced by inter-thread locks, the result would be UB.

Comment: @PeterDanielJohannsen vectors and arrays don't sort automatically. If you don't need dynamic memory, arrays will be faster. I prefer std::array<std::array<type, size1>, size2> over [size1][size2] because you get all the benefits of a container.

Comment: @PeterDanielJohannsen also, there's no reason to assume that just for filling a container, threads will increase speed.